# Replace string column endwiths specific substrings under condition of another column with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-re

Given a dataset as follows:

```
   id  company name  value
0   1    Finl Corp.      7
1   2  Fund Tr Corp      6
2   3   Inc Invt Fd      5
3   4  Govt Fd Inc.      3
4   5   Trinity Inc      5
```

Or:

```
[{'id': 1, 'company name': 'Finl Corp.', 'value': 7},
 {'id': 2, 'company name': 'Fund Tr Corp', 'value': 6},
 {'id': 3, 'company name': 'Inc Invt Fd', 'value': 5},
 {'id': 4, 'company name': 'Govt Fd Inc.', 'value': 3},
 {'id': 5, 'company name': 'Trinity Inc', 'value': 5}]
```

I need to replace if `company name` column's contents endwiths `['Corp.', 'Corp', 'Inc.', 'Inc']`, while at same time `value` is `>= 5`

The expected result will be:

```
   id  company name  value
0   1          Finl      7
1   2       Fund Tr      6
2   3   Inc Invt Fd      5
3   4  Govt Fd Inc.      3
4   5       Trinity      5
```

How could I acheive that in Pandas and regex?

Trial code with error: `TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'`

```
mask = (df1['value'] >= 5)
df1.loc[mask, 'company_name_concise']= df1.loc[mask, 'company name'].str.replace(r'\bCorp.|Corp|Inc.|Inc$', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change values in regex by add `\s*` for spaces with `$` for end of strings:

```
mask = (df1['value'] >= 5)


L = ['Corp.', 'Corp', 'Inc.', 'Inc']
pat = '|'.join(f'\s*{x}$' for x in L)

df1.loc[mask, 'company name']= df1.loc[mask,'company name'].str.replace(pat,'',regex=True)

print (df1)
   id  company name  value
0   1          Finl      7
1   2       Fund Tr      6
2   3   Inc Invt Fd      5
3   4  Govt Fd Inc.      3
4   5       Trinity      5
```

Comment: Thanks, but I find `Inc Invt Fd` in the third row has a small problem, `Inc` shouldn't get replaced since `Inc` is not endwith, but in the beginning.

Comment: @ahbon - added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace` takes *two* arguments, the pattern and the replacement:

```py
mask = (df1['value'] >= 5)
df1.loc[mask, 'company_name_concise']= df1.loc[mask, 'company name'].str.replace(r'\b(?:Corp\.?|Inc\.?)$', '', regex=True)
```

Note that the regex pattern you want here is:

```regex
\b           word boundary
(?:
    Corp\.?  match Corp or Corp.
    |        OR
    Inc\.?   match Inc or Inc.
)
$            at the end of the company name
```

Comment: Should the period after `Inc` be escaped by a backslash as well ?   i.e.  `Inc\.?` instead of `Inc.?` ?

Comment: @SeaBean You are correct.  I had answered from a cell phone.  Easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Or for length of code you could just directly modify the whole column and assign by index:

```
df.loc[df['value'] > 5, 'company name'] = df['company name'].str.replace(r'\bCorp.|Corp|Inc.|Inc$', '')
>>> df
```

---

```
   id  company name  value
0   1         Finl       7
1   2      Fund Tr       6
2   3   Inc Invt Fd      5
3   4  Govt Fd Inc.      3
4   5   Trinity Inc      5
>>>
```

Or a solution with `np.where`:

```
>>> df['company name'] = np.where(df['value'] > 5, df['company name'].str.replace(r'\bCorp.|Corp|Inc.|Inc$', ''), df['company name'])
>>> df
   id  company name  value
0   1         Finl       7
1   2      Fund Tr       6
2   3   Inc Invt Fd      5
3   4  Govt Fd Inc.      3
4   5   Trinity Inc      5
>>>
```